# Convert epoch to human-readable date string, how can I make my code shorter?

Tags: elixir

I'm converting `timestamp`, which is a Unix epoch (in seconds) to a human-readable format. `trunc` is piped to convert exponential number to int. How can I make my code shorter?

```
  def format_timestamp(timestamp) do
    timestamp
        |> trunc
        |> DateTime.from_unix!(:second)
        |> (fn t -> 
            date = [t.year, t.month, t.day]
            |> Enum.map(&to_string/1)
            |> Enum.map(&String.pad_leading(&1, 2, "0"))
            |> Enum.join("-")

            timing = [t.hour, t.minute, t.second]
            |> Enum.map(&to_string/1)
            |> Enum.map(&String.pad_leading(&1, 2, "0"))
            |> Enum.join(":")

            ~s(#{date}T#{timing}.#{t.time_zone |> String.replace("Etc/UTC", "000Z")})
        end).()
  end
```

Edit: Input is epoch in seconds (integer). Desired output is string in this format: `2020-04-09T09:26:12.000Z` with leading zeros for month, day, hour, minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention what your input and desired output is. If UTC is fine, the simplest way is to use [`DateTime.to_string/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DateTime.html#to_string/1):

```elixir
1586490833
|> DateTime.from_unix!()
|> DateTime.to_string
```

Output:

`"2020-04-10 03:53:53Z"`

Your algorithm returns `"2020-04-10 03:53:53 UTC"`. To get that, you could replace the `Z` using [`String.replace/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#replace/4):

```elixir
1586490833
|> DateTime.from_unix!()
|> DateTime.to_string
|> String.replace("Z", " UTC")
```

Or you could build your own string using the [`zone_abbr`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DateTime.html#t:t/0) property of `DateTime`:

```elixir
{:ok, dt} = DateTime.from_unix(1586490833)
"#{DateTime.to_date(dt)} #{DateTime.to_time(dt} #{dt.zone_abbr}"
```

Comment: The latest one is the way to go.

Comment: Input is epoch in seconds (integer). Desired output is string in this format: `2020-04-09T09:26:12.000Z` with leading zeros in month, day, hour, minutes, seconds.

Comment: If you just need an ISO-8601 string, then `DateTime.to_iso8601/1` should be good enough (it won't print the milliseconds though, because there are none when the input is in seconds).

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
def format_timestamp(timestamp) do
  "#{
    timestamp
    |> DateTime.from_unix!()
    |> DateTime.to_naive()
    |> NaiveDateTime.to_string()
  } UTC"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For the full control, I would go with creating our own *formatter* for what ISO-8601 string that comes out from `DateTime.to_iso8601!/1`.

```rb
@date_delim ?-
@time_delim ?:
@zone_suffix " UTC"

# 20200410T040640Z
def format_timestamp(<<
  y1, y2, y3, y4, m1, m2, d1, d2, ?T,
  h1, h2, i1, i2, s1, s2, ?Z
>>), do: <<
  y1, y2, y3, y4, @date_delim, m1, m2, @date_delim, d1, d2, ?\s,
  h1, h2, @time_delim, i1, i2, @time_delim, s1, s2, @zone_suffix >>

def format_timestamp(timestamp) when is_integer(timestamp) do
  timestamp
  |> DateTime.from_unix!()
  |> DateTime.to_iso8601(:basic)
  |> format_timestamp()
end
```

For everything else, the last answer provided by Adam Millerchip using `dt.zone_abbr` would be the best fit.

Comment: what I find strange is that standard library doesn't provide time formatting by provided string, is that a choice by design or it will be implemented someday?

Comment: @Daniel there is [`strftime/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/calendar/Calendar.Strftime.html#strftime/3)